# Basic question on Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have model xyz.rb and model abc.rb. No relation between them. If want to print any attribute from xyz in abc views/print/show.html.erb how??

I know very basic but looking for good explanation.

Comment: You're really going to have to put a little more effort into explaining your question. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Suppose I have user and report and I want to show report's created_at in user/show.html.erb. is that help?

Comment: In future, try to have a better question title than "Basic question on Ruby Rails". We know that it's Ruby on Rails because of the tags, and everything on Stack Overflow is a question, so you don't need to have "question" in the question title.

Answer (score 5):

You can access any model from any controller, view or helper method. Mvc means model, controllers and views are related but there's no limitation on access between them. The normal thing to do would be to store the reports to an instance variable in any controller then output them in the view:

```
#print_controller.rb

def show
  @reports = Report.find_by_some_attribute(...

#show.html.erb

<%- @reports.each do |report| -%>
  <%= report.created_at -%>
<%- end -%>
```

I really think though that you need to find a better approach to learning rails. This is very basic like you say and I would recommend you buy a book. Do you speak English well, or what's your native language?

Comment: I speak arabic, my english suck!

Comment: Your English is definitely better than my Arabic. :) I don't know if there are any good Arabic rails resources. What you could do though is have a look at railscasts.com. They're in English but you can follow as the 'caster works through the code, and you'll find the source code available for each tutorial. I think looking at other peoples code is one of the best ways to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
XYZ.all.each do |xyz|
  some(xyz)
end
```

Details you can find [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Assuming @x is an instance of Xyz model, you can do print any attribute of @x object.

If you dont have @x object. You can find it and instantiate @x in the show action of the abc controller. @x = Xyz.first for example.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example, if you have two models User and Report. You can access Report's created_at from User's controller,view,etc.
You need to write something like this:

```
Report.find_by_created_at("2013-11-12 14:43:44.11824")
```

You can refer ruby on rails guides to learn rails. Also you can find basic active record explanations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

This very basic but i am giving best solution to this

## in abc controller

```
def show
  @reports = Report.where(:attribute => value)
end

it will get the all records basic on that value

<h1>views/abc/show.html.erb</h1>
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
  <%= report.attribute_name %>
 <%end%>
```